# Big O in integral representation of arctan

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

Why does this equality hold?

$$\int_{0}^{T/c}\frac{du}{1+u^2} = \int_{0}^\infty \frac{du}{1+u^2}+O(c/T)$$

Comment: Because for large $u$, $\dfrac1{u^2+1}\simeq u^{-2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be written
$$
\int_{0}^{A}\frac{du}{1+u^2} = \int_{0}^\infty \frac{du}{1+u^2}+O(1/A)\quad\text{as } A \to \infty
$$
and equivalently
$$
\int_{A}^\infty\frac{du}{1+u^2} = O(1/A)\quad\text{as } A \to \infty
$$
which is easy: for $A>0$
$$
\int_{A}^\infty\frac{du}{1+u^2} < \int_{A}^\infty\frac{du}{u^2} = \frac{1}{A} .
$$

Answer (score 2):

Cauchy's inequality gives that

$$
(u^2+1^2)(1^2+1^2)\ge(u+1)^2
$$

so we have

$$
\int_{T/c}^\infty{\mathrm du\over1+u^2}\le2\int_{T/c}^\infty{\mathrm du\over(1+u)^2}={2c\over c+T}=\mathcal O\left(\frac cT\right)
$$